# Can I use Entity Framework on Windows Phone 8

Tags: entity-framework, windows-phone-7, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to use Entity Framework to save data to a SQL CE database in isolated storage on Windows Phone 8?

When I try and add a reference to EF 5 using NuGet I get the error:

"Failed to add reference to 'System.Data.Entity'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache."

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on using EF with Windows Phone: http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/using-entity-framework-create

Comment: The link shows a workaround on how to not use entity framework on windows phone but instead to generate the models in a windows class then port them to windows phone. Not really what I'm looking for I'm afraid.

Comment: EF requires System.Data.dll which is currently not supported on Windows Phone.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear but at least I know now. Please make that an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @steve/Pawel   move comment to answer please so question is closed. Answer yourself Steve if pawel doesnt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482525/windows-phone-8-mvvm-database-first-like-ef

Comment: The nightly builds of E7 target wpa81 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this with VS2013 and EF6 still same problem.

But what is supported (although with limited functionality) is Linq to SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872(v=vs.105).aspx

At least you get the same ORM style of data access.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet but there is a version of Entity Framework called Entity Framework Everywhere that is currently under development but they seam to be mainly focusing on SQL lite.
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Entity%20Framework%20Everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can starting from EF 7.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Using-EF7-in-Windows-Phone-Store-Applications

Comment: They have temporarily disabled store/phone support until they nail down the aspnet5 piece: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/12/02/ef7-priorities-focus-and-initial-release.aspx