# Windows Phone 8 MVVM Database First (like EF)

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, windows-phone-8, poco

Is there any framework for Windows Phone 8 which is similar in use to Entity Framework for generating POCOS from an existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to SQL: A SQL Server Compact database combined with my SQL Server Compact Toolbox for the code generation. If you have VS Express, you can use the standalone edition, download from http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com

Comment: I am having VS Express for Windows Phone. The issue is that SQL Server Compact toolbox doesn't seem to appear in VS 2012 Express

Comment: Updated reply just now